# Garbage Collection in Java application

Tags: java

I've searched a lot on how to configure the garbage collector in a Java application, but found answers on GC tuning and using some -XX arguments.

There is also no information on where to use these -XX arguments in Java app.

How do I configure this?

Comment: [Rules of Optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimization)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that if you don't need to tune your GC's performance, you don't need to specify any GC options at all.

The Java JVM is capable of adjusting the GC's behavior reasonably well to meet the  runtime needs of typical Java applications.  If it is doing a good job, you don't need any GC options at all.  If not, then<sup>1</sup> you tune the GC

Indeed, I would say that (with the possible exception of `-Xmx`) all GC related JVM options are GC **tuning** options.  So the (Oracle or Android or ... pick your vendor) documentation on Java GC tuning is *precisely* where you should start looking for advice on GC options.

---

<sup>1 - And not before!</sup>

Comment: In an interview, interviewer asked, "How do we configure GC in our java app"?  What should be the answer?

Comment: See my answer ... above!  The specific answer will depend on what needs to be tuned.

Comment: And the general answer is that before you go to your next answer, you should read the Oracle documentation on GC tuning ... so that you *understand* what the interviewer is asking, and give him / her an appropriate response.  (But, as indicated, my initial response would be to ask the interviewer what the GC goal of the tuning is.)